# Angular Form - "Required" with ng-model-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form with two fields:

```
<form name="form">
    <input type="email" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: blur }" required />
    <input type="password" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: blur }" required />
    <div ng-show="form.password.$error.required">Password required</div>
</form>
```

The error div is always displayed when the password field is empty - I only want it to display if the password has been focused and then blurred. Is there a simple change I can make to enable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div ng-show="form.password.$error.required && form.password.$dirty">Password required</div>
```

You can do this by adding condition of dirty field. So if the field will be dirt then only it will show error

Answer (score 1):

This should work using the `$pristine` property.

```
<div ng-show="!form.password.$pristine && form.password.$error.required">Password required</div>
```

`$pristine` returns true if user has not interacted with the control yet.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

Answer (score 0):

You'd want something like `$dirty` (changed from default value) or `$touched` (blurred at least once, probably what you want, based on your model options).

### Example

```
form name="form">
    <input type="email" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: blur }" required />
    <input type="password" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: blur }" required />
    <div ng-messages="form.password.$error" ng-if="form.password.$touched">
      <div ng-message="required">Password required</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I used `ng-messages` here because it's neat, but you don't have to use it, you can just add the condition to your `ng-show` / `ng-if`.

### References

- [ngMessages](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages)
- [$touched](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$touched)